# javascript ul button dropdown crashes after if doing more than 1 button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

So i have a button drop down list that i want users to select  a choice, and basically the button will return the users selection.Pretty straight forward, tested on jsFiddle and works great. Using ruby on rails btw, so i'm not sure if it might conflicting the way rails handle javascript actions.

Heres the code:

```
  <%= form_for(@user, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
   <p>Do you have experience in Business? If yes, select one of the following:
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select one <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li ><a href="#">Entrepreneurship</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#">Investments</a></li>
      <li ><a href="#">Management</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li ><a href="#">All of the Above</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /btn-group -->
  <%= f.text_field :years_business , :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Years of experience" %>
 </div>
```

Now there are 2 more of these, and basically what happens is that if I select an item for the first time from the dropdown list, everything works great. But the moment I select the same button/or new button, the page immediately kind of refreshes, they selected value will not show up after the list drops down and user selects a value. I viewed the page source and 
added additional javascript src and types, but still doesnt work.
the jquery code:

```
   jQuery(function ($) {
$('.input-group-btn .dropdown-menu > li:not(.divider)').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('ul').prev().text($(this).text())
})
});
```

Any suggestions what is causing the problem?? The jsfiddle link is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/w4s8u/7/

Comment: The page does not refresh in the fiddler example you provided. Am I missing something?

Comment: the refresh happens on my website, after the user signs up. This is a page after the user provided their email and password

Comment: Might be the case that when u click on the menu item, you actually click on the link with href=#. This would make the page seem like its reloading.

Comment: Is it possible to provide just the URLs before and after the refresh you are mentioning?

Comment: inyourshoes.herokuapp.com, after signing up with email you'll see the button page

Comment: And after selecting the same button twice, there isn't any hash in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this handler function will fix your issue:

```
 $('.input-group-btn .dropdown-menu > li > a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('ul').prev().text($(this).text())
        })
```

Comment: Well, I copied that page to my localhost. Its almost exact copy but I commented out javascripts that are not bootstrap or jquery.  It works fine on my end and does not "refersh".  There is a chance one of those script is causing this behavior.

Comment: could you tell me which scripts you commented out?

Comment: try starting with turbolink one.

Comment: wont work, cause rails depends on the turbolink for javascript =\

Comment: ahh. didn't notice ur rails tag

Comment: wow i found the problem, it was the anchor tag with "#". Apparently that jumps to the top of the page. if i include "#!" in the anchor tag it works now........ ugh